# Прочитать строку до определённого символа

Tags: php

Допустим, есть строка `12345:45`. Я написал кусок кода, который оставляет только то, что идёт после двоеточия. А как теперь сделать так, чтобы осталось всё, что идёт до двоеточия?

```
$lat = explode(':', $coordinates);
$lat = end($lat);
```

Comment: `end` - указатель на последний элемент, `reset` - на первый. Не слишком гармонирует, но это же ПэХаПэ...

Comment: Да просто `$lat[0]`...

Comment: Вам нужно использовать обе части (до и после двоеточия) или только какую-то одну?

Answer (score 1):

```
list($lat1, $lat2) = explode(':', $coordinates);
```